# How to shorten startup time after Lion to Mountain Lion upgrade?

Tags: macos, upgrade, startup

I have been looking for answers since and have seen a few that say I need to do a fresh install and whatnot. I am simply unhappy with the fact that I just bought a brand new laptop that got a free Mountain Lion upgrade and now regretting it because the startup time is over 1 minute.

I'm not a techy person and I don't know how to do a fresh install. I refuse to do so if I have to pay for another Mountain Lion download.

How to fix the slow computer start, to make start up time as it was before?

Comment: You don’t have to pay for a fresh install. Just download it again and do what you did before. You won’t even lose any data.

Comment: "You won’t even lose any data." That's not a FRESH install. A fresh install constitutes the backing up and formatting of the drive, installing the OS then restoring needed personal files.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've paid once for an OS upgrade, you own the right to download the OS again at any time. Reinstalling will **not** require another purchase. If you wish to try your luck with a fresh in a fresh install, consider watching TLDToday's video series:

[How to Create a Bootable Mountain Lion 10.8 USB Install Thumb Drive](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aee0rZXowEA&feature=plcp)

[How to Clean Install OS 10.8 Mountain Lion](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8G9m4yzxAg&feature=relmfu)

Answer (score 0):

Long start up times are sometimes indicative of a few things:

**File System issues** - if the Mac shuts down improperly then on start up, it will take the time to perform a quick scan of the file system.  If by starting up and shutting down the system, on the next statup the boot time is still long then you should consider using Disk Utility to "Repair File Permissions" and "Check/Repair Disk"

**External USB Device** - if you have external devices plugged into your laptop at boot time, dependant on the device type e.g. external USB disk drive, then the USB probing of the devices will increase your startup time.